# SQL Server 2008 install error: VS2008 SP1?

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, sql, visual-studio-2008

I'm installing the developer edition of SQL Server 2008 and it's giving me the error:

"A previous release of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is installed on this computer. Upgrade Microsoft VS2008 to the SP1 before installing SQL Server 2008."

Except that I already have VS2008SP1 installed. Anyone know what else it might be referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Web Developer installed?  [This article](http://dotnetslackers.com/Visual_Studio/re-128953_Problems_Installing_SQL_Server_2008_After_Installing_Visual_Studio_2008_SP1_Make_Sure_You_ve_Updated_or_Uninstalled_Visual_Web_Developer.aspx) describes a situation where this can arise

Also if you installed any pre-release or beta versions of any of these components, this could cause problems and they should be uninstalled and the released versions installed.

Comment: I'm in the process of removing anything that looks suspicious. We'll see if that does it.

Comment: Looks like I'm off and running. It was one of the SQL installs put there by VS2008. I removed everything that had "SQL" in it, though this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844945/sql-server-2008-installation-error-previous-releases-of-microsoft-visual-studio) indicated the VS2008 Shell was the culprit.